# PHP Codeigniter: SQL syntax error `WHERE username = $username`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I try to add `$username` into MySQL query as follows. But the query fails with SQL syntax error.

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp_user UNION SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = ".$username."";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

What's wrong with this query?

> Here is error message Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SELECT * FROM temp_user UNION SELECT * FROM member WHERE username =

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/dex/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Comment: maybe a single quote issue? `... username = '".$username."'.....`. And do these two tables share the same number of columns?

Comment: not working sorry. I'm not sure. Codeigniter can use union?

Comment: How many columns are there in `temp_user` and `member` table?

Comment: tempuser 6 columns  and member 5 columns

Comment: well there ya go. What sort of mutated resultset would that be !

Comment: The number of columns should match while using `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, no need for string concatenation

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM temp_user UNION SELECT * FROM member WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Comment: sorry not working.  may be codeigniter cannot use UNION?

Comment: first there is no correlation of codeigniter and `union` query and when i tried this query on my sql client with name column on two table having same amount of values it is working.

Comment: Ok I found error that is  the star *   cannot use with union

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax error is likely due to this part:

```
"... WHERE username = ".$username."";
```

You should [escape](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries) `$username`

That is

```
"... WHERE username = ".$this->db->escape($username);
```

where `$conn` is a `mysqli` object representing the link identifier.

Comment: Ok I found error that is the star * cannot use with union

Answer (score -1):

Solved!!!  because of  i cannot use star(*) with union

$sql = "SELECT username FROM temp_user WHERE username = '".$username."' UNION SELECT username FROM member WHERE username = '".$username."'";

Comment: you still need to escape `$username`, because the query will fail if `$username = "\'string"`, for instance.